# Using a loop to define variable value JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, list

I'm using javascript and JQuery.

let's assume there's an array, ListArray and it's got a bunch of sentences inside. Simple.

Can I somehow do this?

```
var List = for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //loop through an array here to generate the contents
}
```

I need to generate a lot of list groups, and within each of those list groups, generate a list, and the lists' contents are stored in an array.

**So how can I generate this list from the array and store it in that variable?**

the variable should have an outcome of

```
var List = "<p>Some content from an array</p><p>Some content from an array</p><p>Some content from an array</p>";
```

**To be clear,** I'm asking if it's valid to put an for loop within a variable in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to the variable inside the loop:

```
var list = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   list += '<p>' + generateContentForGroup(i) + '</p>';
}
```

where `generateContentForGroup` would somehow get the ith array and generate from it the content you want.

---

> I'm asking if it's valid to put an for loop within a variable in JS.

No it's not. This would result in a *syntax error*. On the right hand side of a variable declaration with assignment can only be an *expression*:

```
var variable_name = expression;
```

A `for` loop is a *statement* and hence cannot be used in place of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a bit of [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var arr = [
             "Some content from an array",
             "More content from an array",
             "Even more content from an array"
          ];
var str = $.map(arr,function(e){ return "<p>" + e + "</p>"}).join('');
//output: <p>Some content from an array</p><p>More content from an array</p><p>Even more content from an array</p>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/s874S/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ary = ["some text1","some text2","some text3"];
var list = "";
var len = ary.lengthl
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    list += "<p>"+ary[i]+"</p>";
}
```